# I'm unable to remove the code that I used to restrict access to the profile page for subscribers

Tags: php, wp-admin

Even after I removed the code, I am still getting the error message "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." please help me to fix this

```php
function remove_read_wpse_93843(){  
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'read' );    
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_read_wpse_93843' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_read_wpse_93843(){
  $role = get_role( 'subscriber' ); 
  $role->add_cap( 'read' );
} 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_read_wpse_93843' );
```

This code is work for me

Comment: Yes that's right: remove_cap() removes the role from the database and add_cap() puts it back. Note that you only need to run this once: you can remove this code again, although it's possibly OK to leave as it won't do extra database writes if the role already has the capability.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you help me redirect to another page?